# Activerecord relation in Ruby with extra filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following classes, a Word Occures in a Filename. The relation works but I would like to drop the extra checking while I enumerate the result.

```
class Filename < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(:adapter => "sqlite3",:database  => "db/filenames.db")
  has_many :occurances
  has_many :words, through: :occurances
end

class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(:adapter => "sqlite3",:database  => "db/words.db")
  has_many :occurances
  has_many :filenames, through: :occurances
end

class Occurance < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(:adapter => "sqlite3",:database  => "db/occurances.db")
  belongs_to :filename
  belongs_to :words
end
```

I enumerate the result like this, Filename has a field org which i need to check, it can have other values.

```
words = Word.where("word like ?", "%test%")
words.each do |word|
  word.occurances.each do |occurance|
    filename = occurance.filename
    next unless filename.org == 55 # I would like to avoid this
    # rest of the code
  end
end
```

How can I do the check for org in my where clausule ?

Comment: Try this `Word.includes(occurrences: :filename).where("word like ?", "%test%").where(:occurrences => {:filename => {org: 55}})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
word.occurrences.joins(:filenames).where(filenames: { org: 55 }).each { |occurrence| ... }
```

Not sure if JOIN's across databases would ever work though.

Comment: Thnx, I get no such table: occurances, could be the join or includes have problem with multiple database, I'll try to put them together to test if that is the reason

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do it like this:

```
words = Word.includes(:filenames)
            .where("word like ?", "%test%")
            .where(filenames: { org: 55 } })
```

Comment: thnx, bu I get no such table: filenames , the tables are in different databases because i load them in memory when i do updates and saving them back only works if I have one table per database